# What determines what shows up in Azure Devops backlog?

Tags: tfs, azure-devops

I am using Azure DevOps Server Version Dev17.M153.3 - self-hosted Azure DevOps.

I have tried but can't figure out what are the rules for what items show up in the backlog. The backlog configuration is to see only User Stories.

Let's say my Team is "DevOps." I have drag/dropped several User Stories and child Tasks onto "DevOps Team Backlog" and then I go to the Backlog sprint and they are not there, but 2 random tasks are, that have

`Area: DevOps, Iteration: DevOps\Some Product\Some Sprint`

I can go find the items I drag/dropped onto the backlog under Work Items, and they have

`Area: DevOps, Iteration: DevOps`

If I use the "Create Query" function on the backlog, the query is

`Work Item Type: User Story, Area: DevOps, Iteration: DevOps, State: New,Active,Resolved`

and many items show up, which is what I expect to see in the Backlog view.

**What are the rules to determine what shows up in my team's backlog view?**

Comment: Did you start by reading the documentation on how backlogs work?

Comment: @DanielMann Yes, I'm sure it's in there somewhere but nothing jumps out at me as something I'm doing wrong. My Backlog Iteration is setup as "DevOps" in this example.

Comment: Embarrassingly, part of my problem was I had a search filter set in my backlog.

Comment: Make sure the Stories you want in your team backlog are in the Teams's area path.  If not they will not show up on the backlog.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You use backlogs (user stories) to define your future work.

[image]

2. You plan your next iteration by assign user stories to that iteration in the backlog

[image]

3. You create child tasks in the sprint backlog

   [image]

Additional links:

1. [Organize your backlog, map child work items to parents](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/boards/backlogs/organize-backlog?view=azure-devops)
2. [Assign backlog items to a sprint](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/boards/sprints/assign-work-sprint?view=azure-devops)
3. [Add tasks to backlog items](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/boards/sprints/add-tasks?view=azure-devops)